# Equivalent definitions of a heavy-tailed distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, distribution-tails

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx}dF(x)=\infty \text{ for all } t>0 \Leftrightarrow  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}e^{tx}\mathbb{P}[X>x]= \infty \text{ for all }t >0$.

I proved the $\Leftarrow $ direction directly using Chernoff bound but I am unable to prove the $\Rightarrow $ direction. Any idea or hint? Thank you!

Comment: You might be asking this question twice. In that case ideal course of action is to edit your old post to draw attention.

Comment: @StubbornAtom How do you know? I deleted the duplicate just before posting this one. Editing a question doesn't push it up, how it draw attention?

Comment: Editing does push it up on the list of active questions at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sketch proof of $\implies$'s contrapositive:

By L'Hôpital's rule, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\Bbb P(X>x)}{e^{-tx}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F^\prime(x)}{te^{-tx}}$, so if this is finite for some $t>0$, $\int_{\Bbb R}e^{tx/2}F^\prime(x)dx$ is also finite.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please expand on why the finiteness of that limit implies $\int_{\Bbb R}e^{tx/2}F^\prime(x)dx$ is also finite?

Comment: @John11 Choose $A,\,c$ so $x\ge c\implies F^\prime(x)\le Ae^{-tx}$. Then $0\le\int_{-\infty}^ce^{tx/2}F^\prime(x)dx\le\int_{-\infty}^cF^\prime(x)dx=F(c)$, while $0\le\int_c^\infty e^{tx/2}F^\prime(x)dx\le A\int_c^\infty e^{-tx/2}dx$.